# How can I use Termux with the JuiceSSH interface?

Tags: keyboard, termux

I would like to use Termux and its package manager as a local terminal, but I cannot get used to its keyboard. The volume buttons are a poor choice IMO, as they require significant finger pressure and only work some of the times, at least on my phone (OnePlus 6.)

On the contrary, I find JuiceSSH's keyboard and overall terminal interface perfect.

Can I use JuiceSSH to open a local Termux session? How?

If that's not possible, is there a plugin for Termux that makes the keyboard work more like JuiceSSH's?

I tried executing Termux's bash from a JuiceSSH "local" session, but they are run under different Unix users (u0_a214 vs u0_a198) and so anything I try to do gives Permission Denied.

Comment: Termux is an open source app. If you have suggestions how it could/should be improved you should create an issue in the GitHub project: https://github.com/termux/termux-app

Answer (score 1):

It's already supported.

I created a `~/.termux/termux.properties` with the following contents:

```
extra-keys = [ \
 ['ESC','|','/','-','HOME','UP','END','PGUP'], \
 ['TAB','CTRL','ALT','DEL','LEFT','DOWN','RIGHT','PGDN'] \
]
extra-keys-style = arrows-only
```

It's enabled by opening the left sidebar (swipe from the left screen edge) and long-pressing on the "keyboard" button.

Documentation here: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Touch_Keyboard